# Adding Virtio block devices at runtime in Libvirt KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, libvirt, debian-wheezy, virsh

I'm running Debian Wheezy Beta 4 with KVM based guest systems which run the same operating system. I'm using LibVirt to manage the virtualisation.

What I would like to do is to attach an LVM based block device to a running guest system through Virtio. If I would configure it through `virsh edit [MACHINE]` it would look like this:

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source dev='/dev/volume_group/logical_volume'/>
  <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
```

I tried to find out how to do this with `virsh attach-disk`. So far I figured the following:

```
virsh attach-disk guest /dev/volume_group/logical_volume vdb --driver qemu --type raw --cache none --persistent
```

How can I specify the target's `bus` and driver's `io` field? I really need these options to be exactly as specified in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

These days virsh(1) has all the command-line options, you can simply run e.g.:

```
sudo virsh attach-disk \
           --domain guestname \
           --source /dev/volume_group/logical_volume \
           --target vdb \
           --driver qemu \
           --subdriver raw \
           --cache none \
           --io native \
           --targetbus virtio \
           --config \
           --live
```

`virsh attach-disk --help` shows it all.

Comment: This solved it for me. Best up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find the commandline way of specifying the options quite limited. Try using the [`attach-device` action](http://builder.virt-tools.org/artifacts/libvirt-virshcmdref/html/chap-Virsh_Command_Reference-Commands.html#sect-attach-device) and specify the disk configuration in an XML file.

```
virsh # attach-device [MACHINE] /tmp/new-disk.xml
```

with the `new-disk.xml` file containing the five lines you would add using `edit`.

Add `--persistent` to have it update your machine's XML definition for you.

*update*

Make sure to have the hotplug kernel modules loaded in the guest before adding the device:

```
modprobe acpiphp
modprobe pci_hotplug
```

You should then see the kernel throwing some debug messages in `dmesg`, like this:

```
[  321.946440] virtio-pci 0000:00:06.0: using default PCI settings
[...]
[  321.952782]  vdb: vdb1 vdb2
```

Comment: I'm always getting the following message: `error: Failed to attach device from new-disk.xml` and then `error: End of file while reading data: Input/output error`. Afterwards the libvirt daemon process is gone and I need to restart it. The exact same XML snippet works fine if I paste it manually in `virsh edit [MACHINE]`

Comment: "End of file while reading data: Input/output error" -- sufficient permissions on the file for the user which Libvirtd runs as? and "the libvirt daemon process is gone and I need to restart it" seems a bug to me.

Comment: The file is world-readable. I guess it's some kind of bug.