# KVM and Libvirt - How do I hotplug a new virtio disk?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, storage, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I am trying to hot-add a file-based disk to a running KVM virtual server. I've created a new disk from scratch using the command

```
dd of=/home/cloud/vps_59/test.img bs=1 seek=5G count=0
```

and I was hoping to get it hot-added to the guest by doing this in the virsh shell:

```
virsh # attach-disk vps_59 /home/cloud/vps_59/test.img \
        vdd --driver=file --subdriver=raw
```

The XML definition of the domain then becomes:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source file='/home/cloud/vps_59/root.img'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='file' type='raw'/>
  <source file='/home/cloud/vps_59/test.img'/>
  <target dev='vdd' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
```

As you can see, the driver name becomes wrong, it should be `driver name='qemu'` as the existing `vda` disk. I have tried with `--drive=qemu` but it states it is unsupported.

Secondly, I only "see" the newly added drive once I reboot the virtual machine running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. How can I make the drive "hotplug"? I want the virtual machine to "see" the new drive immediately without a reboot.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion, use `qemu-img` instead of `dd` - its arguments come more natural and does the same thing: `qemu-img create test.img 5G`

Answer (score 34):

I'd like to start with a note that you should avoid using `virsh attach-disk` with its limited amount of options. Instead, I'd suggest to specify the exact disk format you prefer in a separate, temporary XML file or by using the virt-manager GUI application (for the latter, skip the first step).

1. Create a temporary file with a disk definition *like* this one below.

   **adjust the properties to fit your situation**

   ```
   <disk type='file' device='disk'>
     <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
     <source file='/path/to/disk-image.img'/>
     <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
   </disk>
   ```

   Tip: Peek into your current XML domain configuration and copy a `<disk>` section from there.

   ```
   virsh dumpxml <domainname>
   ```
2. Now, before adding the disk to a current domain, make sure the required hotplug kernel modules are loaded in the guest.

   Some Linux distributions like recent CentOS/RHEL/Fedora have this built-in in the kernel. In this case, check for `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI`. If it's `y`, then you're all set and you can skip this step.

   ```
   modprobe acpiphp
   modprobe pci_hotplug
   ```

   Consider adding these two modules to `/etc/modules` if you want them to be loaded on boot by default.
3. Add the disk it to the running VM using

   ```
   virsh attach-device <domain name> /path/to/disk.xml
   ```

   Optionally, add the `--persistent` option to let Libvirt update the domain XML definition 'persistent'.
4. Finally, check inside the guest if the disk was indeed hotplug-inserted. The kernel should  be triggered, as can be checked with `dmesg`:

   ```
   [  321.946440] virtio-pci 0000:00:06.0: using default PCI settings
   [...]
   [  321.952782]  vdb: vdb1 vdb2
   ```

   In the above example I've added a disk as `vdb` with two partitions in the partition table.

#### References

- [Linux-KVM wiki - Using PCI Hotplug Support](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Hotadd_pci_devices)
- similar question ["Adding Virtio block devices at runtime in Libvirt KVM"](https://serverfault.com/questions/453456/adding-virtio-block-devices-at-runtime-in-libvirt-kvm)

Comment: Shouldn't you also add `--persistent` to make sure this configuration does not get lost when you power off the virtual machine?